Sample size calculation for Cox regression for comparison of four treatment groups
I need to calculate the required sample size for a future study. We have 4 treatment groups, one of those will be the control group. The goal is to compare each of the 3 treatment groups to the control group. We will calculate hazards ratio for the primary outcome of each treatment group compared to the control group.
I found the package powerSurvEpi in R. I am unsure whether I can use the function ssizeEpi.default if I adjust the alpha for multiple comparisons or whether I need to use a function for non binary covariates as I will do 3 different comparisons? However, all functions for non binary covariates in this package need pilot data, which we do not have.
Can somebody recommend how to do that in R, maybe with this package or something else? Which method do you recommend to adjust alpha for multiple comparisons?
